# На странице выборов нет перевода блока о сроках проведения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Transifex это строки: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/141769796?q=key%3A8be4b5404852718568fadc1ad5672a6a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавили перевод и выкатили на сайт.